# How to add a url suffix before performing a callback in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have a crawler that works just fine in collecting the urls I am interested in. However, before retrieving the content of these urls (i.e. the ones that satisfy rule no 3), I would like to update them, i.e. add a suffix - say '/fullspecs' - on the right-hand side. That means that, in fact, I would like to retrieve and further process - through callback function - only the updated ones. How can I do that?

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('something1'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('something2'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('something3'), deny=('something4', 'something5')), callback='parse_archive'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `process_value` parameter to `lambda x: x+'/fullspecs'` or to a function if you want to do something more complex.

You'd end up with:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('something3'), deny=('something4', 'something5')),
     callback='parse_archive', process_value=lambda x: x+'/fullspecs')
```

See more at: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#basesgmllinkextractor